# Don't resolve DNS wildcards for a domain on local network

Tags: dns, gateway, wildcards, ddns

I've set up a local Mageia Linux server as a gateway, with local DHCP dhcpd and DNS bind9 servers.
The DNS server is also used for a domain name domain.tld, which has a wildcard A/AAAA record.
But I wanted to be able to access all my computers at .domain.tld, that's why I configured a DDNS with dhcpd and bind9, and a domain-search set to "domain.tld".
It works as it should : when I try to resolve a domain name with no tld, it automatically searches it as a subdomain of domain.tld, and since the wildcard catches all subdomains, it'll always find a record and point to domain.tld.

Now the problem is this one : I would like the wildcard to doesn't resolve on the local network br0 but only on wan0, to be able to send a random request and get a domain not found error, instead of it being resolved as domain.tld. This actually causes a problem for people who just type "foobar" in their browser's address bar, because instead of being redirected to their preffered search engine, they're redirected to domain.tld.
Or even better, to only resolve the wildcard when it is accessed by domain.tld directly, but since domain-search is used client side, I don't think it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing additional details, what you are seeking is the "view" feature.  Take a look at the following two links.  Pay attention to the "acl" and "view" statements.

- http://www.howtoforge.com/two_in_one_dns_bind9_views
- http://www.knowplace.org/pages/howtos/split_view_with_bind_9_howto.php

Hope this helps.

R/ Tim